# String to jsonObject

Tags: android, json, android-volley

On the below code i want to use `Response` but it throws JSONException

```
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + response);//output {"error":false}

                    try {
                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response); // java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
```

Sample JSON string:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "uid": "5b081af13eb974.69226352",
    "user": {
        "name": "66699",
        "created_at": "2018-05-25 18:47:21"
    }
}
```

How i should solve this?

Comment: May I get a sample of the string you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: {"error":false,"uid":"5b081af13eb974.69226352","user":{"name":"66699","created_at":"2018-05-25 18:47:21"}}

Comment: You don't get the entire json string right? --> //output {"error":false}

Comment: it might be because your response isn't a serialised JSON, you should modify your web service to make it return a toString version of that JSON. You can try to create a JSONObject out of this string "{\"error\":false} and see if the exception is thrown

Comment: also, as an advice if you create your own web services, you shouldn't send form data requests (aka StringRequests in Volley) when expecting a JSON response. Unless you are using a multipart parameter, just use a JsonRequest, and expect in the web service the parameters to come to you as a JSON.

Comment: the example of this are here : 
 https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: thank you for reply .this is exactly my problem .can you tell me how to create  serialized JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to retrieve the content of your `response` you don't need to use `JSON` while using `POST` request. Instead do something like this :

```
if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yourResponseFromTheWebService")) {

    ...
    Toast
} else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("OtherPossibleResponse")){

    ....
    Toast

} else{

    ....
    Toast      
}
```

in case of GET request you should do something like this :

```
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // display response

                        try {

                            //put response into string
                            JSONArray Jresult = response.getJSONArray("user");


                            for (int i = 0; i < Jresult.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject json_data = Jresult.getJSONObject(i);
                                String lName = json_data.getString("name");
                                String lCreatedAt = json_data.getString("created_at");

//create a model class with your user info like name and created_at and for every user found create a new user object and store its info.
                                _myUser.add(new User(lName, lCreatedAt));
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(getRequest);
```

Comment: So how about arrays?

Comment: the code smaple i posted is for a POST request ! you here clearly you want to use GET request ! check my updated answer